# How to check if SpriteBuilder timeline is done running in code

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

so first I am running an animation.

```
[self.animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"calibrateButtonOut"];
```

If I want to run an animation when that animation has ended, what do I write? I can't find a method that is equal to isDone.

Answer (score 3):

The `CCBAnimationManager` provides two ways to get informed about animations that completed.

1. Using the `setCompletedAnimationCallbackBlock:` method. This way the provided block will be exectued for every completed timeline animation. To check the name of the timeline animation that just completed a develeoper can use the `lastCompletedSequenceName` method.
2. Implementing the `CCBAnimationManagerDelegate` protocol and setting a class up as the delegate of the `CCBAnimationManager`. This way the `CCBAnimationManager` will call `completedAnimationSequenceNamed:` for each completed timeline animation.

Comment: 3. Simply adding a callback keyframe at the end of the timeline. Callback keyframes are added with a Ctrl (or Option?) click, and edited with a doubleclick.